# using authenticated session/user for REST API in eXist-db

Tags: exist-db

I have a public website running from an eXist app. I am now developing an interface for logged in users to edit certain documents through HTML forms and AJAX. I've set up a module in eXist to receive AJAX POST requests through the eXist REST interface (ie. http://www.example.com/exist/rest/db/myapp/api/myxquery.xql). However this module does not seem to be aware of the fact that the user is already logged in!

How do I get the REST module to use the session/authentication of the logged in user?

Am I required to store the user/password in the browser to pass with each REST API request?

If this is not the preferred model for passing data from the browser under user/password, what is eXist's recommended solution?

Many thanks in advance.

(A variation on this question was asked [two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577949/how-to-authenticate-exist-db-users-in-restxq) but received no solutions.)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138283/creating-database-entries-in-exist-db-with-ajax-calls/52234876#52234876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the REST-API from existdb you can only authenticate each request using HTTP Basic Authentication. Also mentioned in the question you referenced.

If you decide to handle AJAX request in your app's `controller.xql` you will need to:

- Add routes for your AJAX requests to the controller
- Make sure you call `login:set-user` for the user session to be picked up
- Make sure the AJAX request sends the cookie:
  For instance, the `fetch` function will send the authorisation cookie
  only if `send-authorization` is true.
- Look at the `output-method` and `serialization` settings, since you will likely want to respond in JSON-format. [useful blog post about this](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/XQuery31)

Comment: Your answers have been a great help - thanks very much.